# Ubuntu install on nexus 7 hangs on Noting disapperance of ubiquity

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm following the instructions on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation using the desktop installer to get Ubuntu on to my nexus 7, but it gets stuck on first boot on 'Applying changes' > Noting disappearance of ubiquity. When I click on 'Details' it's stuck on 'Purging configuration files for ubiquity ...'. It's sat there for an hour so far.

I have switched usb cable and reinstalled stock android (successfully) and tried again as suggested on the wiki page.

I have also tried the manual installing instructions and get a FAILED (remote: (InvalidSize)) error.

Any ideas where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I got round it by installing the image from this link:

[last-good-image](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-preinstalled/last-good-image/)

I had to use an OTG cable and USB keyboard to do the installation (if I tried to configure the wifi then the keyboard stopped functioning - so I installed without specifying the wifi).

Once booted I found I could not `apt-get update`, the work around was to type:

```
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo rm -fr lists
sudo mkdir lists
sudo mkdir lists/partial
```

Then I could `apt-get update` and `upgrade`.

I hope this helps!

/Simon